# what is the true meaning of "line" and "paper" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

what is the true meaning of "line" and "paper" in this context?

It was, however, on a very high
moral and intellectual level, and might be best described as an up-todate
Christianity with Christ's ethics applied to modern problems and
entirely freed from all trace of dogma. "Documentary Religion," as
Davis called it, was not in his opinion religion at all. That name could
only be applied to the personal product of reason and spirituality. Such
was the general **line** of teaching, mixed up with many revelations of
Nature, which was laid down in the successive books of the "Harmonial
Philosophy" which succeeded "Nature's Divine Revelations," and
occupied the next few years of his life. Much of the teaching appeared in
a strange **paper** called "The Univercoelum," and much was spread by
lectures in which he laid before the public the results of his revelations.

Comment: It's *the **line** of approach* (the broad thrust, the focus). Which appeared in an *[obscure, unusual] **academic paper*** (a scholarly treatise).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Please don't post answers as comments, it breaks the format of the site because they can't be edited or properly voted on.

Comment: @IMSoP: Fell free to copy my comment into an answer yourself, and make any changes you want. I can't be bothered to go into any great detail about this particular "spatial metaphor" usage, given the OP has *also* asked a completely unrelated question about the context-dependent meaning of the word ***paper***. Why don't you complain about people asking multiple questions in a single post?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica The problem is that by answering in a comment, you're actually _encouraging_ the asker, because now they have the information they wanted; but you're simultaneously _discouraging_ other answers, because you've said it already. The correct response to a question you think shouldn't be there is to downvote it and/or vote for closure; then either ignore it, or leave a comment helping the asker improve it.

Comment: I'm sure there's *much* more to say about exactly how/why that metaphoric usage works (as is often said, ***All language is metaphor***). I have to say that if someone else had posted *exactly* the text of my comment, I probably wouldn't have upvoted it . (Basically, it would be "too brief" - especially since it answers ***two*** questions! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Why do you think an poor answer makes a good comment?

Comment: @CJDennis: Well, my comment *might* have inspired someone else to expand more on "vector-based" spatial metaphoric usages *(Your **approach** to the problem isn't working, We need to try a different **tack**, This discussion is **going round in circles,...**).* It doesn't seem to have *yet*, but obviously if OP (or any other future visitors to this page) had more of that "background principles" information, that might save them needing to ask closely related questions (such as what do the highlighted metaphoric terms in this comment mean). Give a man ***a fish***, or ***a fishing rod**?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **line** has a wide range of meanings. Here the usage given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/line) is:

> **5** An area or branch of activity

and in that area **line** can also mean *policy*, *direction* or *strategy* for example

> the official line is that... (policy)
>
> my line of reasoning is... (direction)
>
> our line of approach is... (strategy)

The word **paper** isn't quite as diverse but still has many nuances, here  [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/paper) gives as

> **4** An essay or dissertation, especially one read at an academic lecture or seminar or published in an academic journal.